# Elegant & short (pythonic) way to find the lowest unused number

Tags: python

Suppose I am writing file named `foo.001`, but `001` is replaced by the lowest free index based on files which really exist. What is the most elegant way to write this? This is something I use, but it does not look very good, does it?

```
base='foo'
i=0
while True:
    i+=1; name=base+'.%03d'%i
    if not os.path.exists(name): break
# use name here
```

Better suggestions are the most welcome.

**EDIT:** the lookup won't run in parallel, plus I need the lowest unused index (parallel lookup will not always give the lowest one). Also suppose that I can't list all names already used, only test if one exists (I would like to use it not only for files, but named objects in general, and listing is not always possible or efficient).

Comment: This is very inefficient solution, imagine case if file with name `foo.998` exists.

Comment: Is it in any way possible that your code will run in parallel?

Comment: @EvgenySureev: "better suggestions are the most welcome".

Comment: Use filesystem functions to get file with max index.

Comment: @EvgenySureev : show the code. If you ask the OS to list & sort all filenames first, that is even less efficient.

Comment: Looks good to me. It takes just 5 seconds to understand how the script works - isn't it the definition of "pythonic" ?

Comment: You've commented that the proposed solutions break for more than 1000 objects. The format you've given is fixed to 3 digits; what should happen when that overflows?

Comment: @user2357112: The format is NOT fixed, it is only zero-padded to at least 3 decimal places, but can be longer: '%03d'%123456=='123456'.

Comment: @user2357112 it's not fixed to 3 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same amount of statements but maybe slightly more readable. Using [**`itertools.count`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import count

def next_available(base):
    for ext in count(start=1):
        name = '{}.{:03d}'.format(base, ext)
        if not os.path.exists(name):
            return name
```

Comment: itertools.count is what I needed, an iterator without upper bound :) Thanks!

Comment: Just to note, it's possibly not the most efficient way. It may be quicker to query the whole directory, build a set of names, then check against that. I don't have time to check it, but would be interested to find out.

Comment: I am happy with nice code in this case; the current use-case is to find the lowest unused HDF5 group (not filename), where the lookup is sufficiently fast anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob

used_filenames = {name:True for name in glob.glob('foo.[0-9][0-9][0-9]'))}

for i in range(1000):
    prospect = "foo.{:03d}".format(i)
    if prospect not in used_filenames:
        print("The next unused filename is", prospect)
        break
```

Comment: Will break if there is more than 1000 objects, plus not any shorter than the original.

Comment: I based it off your code, which used 3-digit numbers. Feel free to adopt it, and replace the loop with a comprehension once you understand what it's doing.

Comment: '%03d' is not 3-digit numbers, it is left-padded with zeros but can be longer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion:

```
import os
path = '/home/mydir'
existingnumbers = [int(entry.split('.')[1]) for entry in os.listdir(path) if 'foo.' in entry]
potentialnumbers = range(len(existingnumbers)+1)
newfile = 'foo.{0}'.format(min(set(potentialnumbers) - set(existingnumbers)))
```

Comment: OK, easy to change that, see the edit. If you work with a large number of files it is almost certainly more efficient to query the list of files once rather than try in a loop until you find one that is not taken.